# How to launch new Chrome tab from bash?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, chromium, alfred

I'm using an Alfred workflow / global hotkey to run bash scripts:

1. Trigger Hotkey
2. Action Run Script

I'm thinking to use `open -a Google\ Chrome` but I can't think of a way to open a new tab. This will be a very useful tool to have, and I'm curious if anyone else has done this or found a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why but this happens to depend on the URL you pass. This opens in an existing window: `$ google-chrome about:blank` but this opens in a new page: `$ google-chrome chrome://newtab`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this answer isn't perfect, but it definitely works on OSX, thanks to OS Automator

Pretty much, I just simulate a `CMD+T` keypress

```
open -a Google\ Chrome; osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}'`
```

Comment: I ran this in my terminal and got `36:70: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)`